# SharePoint 2019 On-Premises Dev Environment Setup using Node 16.15.0 version

Tags: sharepoint-server, spfx, spfx-webparts, sharepoint-on-prem, 2019

As per Microsoft site SPFx v1.4.1 is also supported on Node.js v12, v14 and v16 (v12.18.1, v14.17.1 and v16.15.0 to be specific) with some tweaking:
[SharePoint Framework development with SharePoint Server 2019 and Subscription Edition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-2019-and-subscription-edition-support)

I have been trying to generate the SharePoint scaffold code using Yeoman generator. I tried using `@microsoft/generator-sharepoint@1.10.0`, `@microsoft/generator-sharepoint@1.12.0` and many more however none of them worked correctly.

Have anyone tried setting up 2019 On-Premises with Node 16? Please let me know different tools versions I should use to generate the scaffolding. I need Gulp, Yo and generator-sharepoint versions.

Answer (score 0):

Try using below SPFx tooling for SharePoint 2019 SPFx development:

1. SharePoint SPFx generator: `v1.4.1`
2. Node.js: `v6` or `v8`
3. NPM: `v3 (with Node.js 6)` or `v5 (with Node.js 8)`
4. Gulp: `v3`
5. Typescript: `v2.4`
6. React: `v15`

Follow below Microsoft official documentations for more information:

1. [SharePoint Framework development tools and libraries compatibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/compatibility)
2. [SharePoint Framework v1.4.1 release notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/release-1.4.1)
3. [SharePoint Framework development with SharePoint Server 2019 and Subscription Edition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-2019-and-subscription-edition-support)

Comment: I am able to create using Node.js v8 however requirement is to using latest supporting version of node which the Microsoft website says 16.15.0. But it doesn't gives detail of other tools version. Is Node.js v16 recommended? if so what version of Yo, Gulp, generator should be used?

Comment: I have not tried it myself so not completely sure if this combination will work or not (but you can try it once): Node: `v16.15.0`, yo: `v2.0.6`, gulp-cli: `v2.3.0` and SPFx generator (@microsoft/generator-sharepoint): `v1.10.0`. Make sure you are selecting correct SP target version (2019) during scaffold and creating & running a JS file as mentioned here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-2019-and-subscription-edition-support#prepare-the-environment-for-sharepoint-framework-development